# Reusing a ViewController in a View Container

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uicontainerview

Im my Storyboard I have 2 container views (see picture):

- upper and lower are tabs in a tab bar
- the upper one contains A (left - TableView) and C. Is is kind of a detail view of A.
- the lower one contains A (right - TableView) and C as well.

C is embedded within a navigation controller, because C needs to be replaced by another view sometimes.

Is there a way to reuse C? I wired it up the way shown in the picture. C is connected to the navigation controller via the (usual) rootview (Navigation) Segue.

But the side effect is that C is only shown on the view that calls C first (either A or B - who was tabbed first). I guess this is because the first view opened takes kind of "ownership" of C.

Q: is there a way to reuse C in this or another way without just copying it?

Thanks for your ideas.

EDIT: the views A/C and B/C are not SplitViews but Container Views (Xcode object library "Container View").

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by upper and lower ? A/C and B/C ? If so are these split view controllers. This question is messy.

Comment: @Ohnomycoco  I just saw my wrong comment(which I deleted): here the corrected comment: A/C is upper, B/C is lower. They are not UISplitviewControllers, but View Containers.